# Google script quota

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I am running an online free computer science education course website. I use Google scripts to evaluate the student quizzes (I use the MCQ script). Yesterday, there was a spike in visitors to my site. I noticed that the quiz scoring script is no longer sending results to students. I checked the failure notification, and it says "Service invoked too many times for one day:"

Is it because of a quota? If there is a quota, then is there any way to increase it?

My class has more than 800 students, so it is likely that they will submit their homework on the very day I post it online. So, I badly need to increase the email quota. If there is any workaround, that will also be very useful to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you deploy the app to run as the user executing, not as you, then it will run with *their* quota. However, they will have to click to authorize sending mail, and it will appear to have come from their own account to themselves.

Comment: I would like to note that this is incorrect for installable triggers, at least now. `Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them.` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions

Answer (score 1):

The quotas are shown on the [dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard) that can be also accessed through a link in the side panel of the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). I'm afraid you hit quotas for email service.

...

EDIT : Ah, didn't see Corey's answer... smart suggestion of course ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an external API (i.e. [Mandrill](//mandrill.com)). Mandrill (it's by Mailchimp, so it's pretty robust) has an easy external API with much larger limits (in the order of thousands).

You can even set the from address so that it wouldn't look spammy (or, really, any different than the normal Google Apps Script send email).

Take a look at [Use Mandrill API in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354200/use-mandrill-api-in-google-apps-script).